# Birthdate Validation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, validation, date

I'm trying to validate a Birthday date but I  can only validate if all filled in.
If I just choose date, there is no alert ("day must be chosen / month must be chosen").
I can't validate a date... 
How to run this validation?

```js
function isbday(day,month,year) {

  var mth = month;
  var dy = day;
  var yr = year;

        if((mth < 1) || (mth > 12));
        else if((dy < 1) || (dy > 31));
        else if(((mth == 4) || (mth == 6) || (mth == 9) || (mth == 11)) && (dy > 30));
        else if((mth == 2) && (((yr % 400) == 0) || ((yr % 4) == 0)) && ((yr % 100) != 0) && (day > 29));
        else if((mth == 2) && ((yr % 100) == 0) && (dy > 29));
        else if((mth == 2) && (dy > 28)) valid = false;

    return false;
 alert("Birthdate must be filled"); 

}

function validate(){
  var day = document.getElementsByName("xday")[0].value;
  var month = document.getElementsByName("xmonth")[0].value;
  var year = document.getElementsByName("xyear")[0].value;
  
  if(day,month,year == null || day,month,year == ""){
     alert("Birthdate must be filled"); 
     
   }else if(birthdate.match(isbday(birthdate))){
     alert("Birthdate must be filled"); 
              }else
     {
    alert("Birthdate success");
   }
  }
```

```html
<tr>
  <td >Birthdate        </td>
                    <td><select name="xday"> 
                    <option value="">Date</option>
                    <script>
              var myDate = new Date();
              var year = myDate.getFullYear();
              for(var i = 1; i < 32; i++){
                  document.write('<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>');
              }
              </script>
                    </select>
                    
                    <select name="xmonth">
                    <option value="">Month</option>
                   <script>
              var myDate = new Date();
              var year = myDate.getFullYear();
              for(var i = 1; i < 13; i++){
                  document.write('<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>');
              }
              </script>
                    </select>
                    
                    <select name="xyear">
                    <option value="">Year</option>
                <script>
              var myDate = new Date();
              var year = myDate.getFullYear();
              for(var i = 1950; i < year; i++){
                  document.write('<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>');
              }
              </script>
                </select>
</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>
     <input type="button" name="btnRegis" onClick="validate()" onsub value="Register"/>
       </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: do you want to disable the Register button until a date is entered or do you want an alert for each part of birthdate not filled in?

Comment: I do not really understand what you are asking. Probably the requiered attribute in the tags might help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way is to change the day select according to the month that was selected but if you still want to do it the same way:

Change a little bit your valid function

Each if statement return **false** if not valid

```
function isVaild(day, month, year) {

  var mth = month;
  var dy = day;
  var yr = year;

  //Checks
  if ((mth < 1) || (mth > 12)) return false;
  else if ((dy < 1) || (dy > 31)) return false;
  else if (((mth == 4) || (mth == 6) || (mth == 9) || (mth == 11)) && (dy > 30)) return false;
  else if ((mth == 2) && (((yr % 400) == 0) || ((yr % 4) == 0)) && ((yr % 100) != 0) && (day > 29)) return false;
  else if ((mth == 2) && ((yr % 100) == 0) && (dy > 29)) return false;
  else if ((mth == 2) && (dy > 28)) return false;

  //Pass all checks
  return true;

}

function validate() {
  var day = document.getElementsByName("xday")[0].value;
  var month = document.getElementsByName("xmonth")[0].value;
  var year = document.getElementsByName("xyear")[0].value;

  //if one is empty
  if (day, month, year === null || day, month, year === "") {
    alert("Birthdate must be filled\nDay, Month, Year is empty");
  } 
  //if not a vaild date
  else if (!isVaild(day, month, year)) {
    alert("Birthdate not vaild");
  } 
  //All good :)
  else {
    alert("Birthdate success");
  }
}
```

Working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/94rxlj80LXbDIKFRYOZF?p=preview)